# Architecture to publish offline data from android app to backend

Tags: android, kotlin, web-applications, architecture, android-workmanager

I am working on app that primarily used in offline condition. User generate data offline and later I schedule a periodic worker that sends the data (Publish) to backend server when device is online

[image]

My publishes looks like the following (This is for user registration)

{
"event":"dbase_mob",
"data":"1,0,Emmanuel,Mtali,1930,Male,0719XX,",
"device_id":"34e01af81782",
"publish_at":1637311191,
"app_version":"2.4.1"
}

- event - describes the type of event database, transaction etc
- data - carry the actual payload the first field is pub_id, other carry additional info
- device_id - unique identifier given to a device
- publish_at - when this was publish was created
- app_version - :)

The publishes gets incremental value as identifier 'pub_id'

**Problems**

- I need to sync the incremental value (pub_id) between server and app.
  Why? The app can be removed from the device! Installing the new app require publishes to continue from the last point
- Any failure to process a publish on the backend service makes hard to debug issues on the client app. (No chance for mistake)
- Edge case can happen where publish can move from say 100 .. 102 skipping the order creating a gap that the backends interprets as a missing publish!

**What I did?**
Concerning the issue of missing publish I have implemented another worker that requests for missing publishes from the server and publish them. This is still chaotic:- Example, if a publish for creating user failed for any reason and the publish for transaction for that specific user arrive to the server it create a data dependency conflict

**Questions**
How can I get rid of additional sync of pub_id
How can I ensure no missing publishes

**Curious**

How some apps like Instagram handle publishing offline data efficiently

Answer (score 1):

The data generate in offline can be in different table or set a flag to determine if it synced or not and update when it successfully push to server.

But still it a really tough topic, there are many things need to handle like will your app install in multiple devices? if so then the continuous incremental id might not work as if 2 local devices have same id and push to service how will you merge them?